# How to bypass the restriction on scripts for people with read-only access to a Google Sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

Is there any way to bypass or work around the restriction that a script doesn't run for people with view-only?

We have a planning where I made a script to go to today's row (which is a couple hundred rows down). I would like that anyone who opens the file, gets to today's date without scrolling for a minute.

If a bypass is not possible, are there any options to achieve the same effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bypass it's not possible, you could

1. use filter views,
2. create links to jump directly the corresponding row

   - You could create the links before hand
   - You could use Google Apps Script to create a web application that creates the link